# unbound method exception when debugging in Visual Studio Code

Tags: linux, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

So I have these two files test.py and translator.py

I'm using test.py to translate a single string using a function in translator.py

The issue is that I am running in to an unbound method exception on a static class method when running test.py from Visual Studio Code, however it works fine on terminal. Below is the snippet causing the issue. Both files are in the same folder.

```
def convertLine(line):
    ...
    # cmd class is defined in translator.py
    cmd = createCmd(line)

    # Verifier.checkCommand is causing the exception 
    if (Verifier.checkCommand(cmd)):
        return True

Class Verifier:

  def checkCommand(cmd):
         # some checks
         Return (true)
```

Comment: What is the exception? What is the error you are getting?

Comment: @ifconfig it was an exception raised during runtime, saying that Verifier.checkCommand was an unbound method.

Comment: There must be more to your code than what you have posted so far. There is not enough here to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is the root problem. But what I found was that it if I surrounded the static functions with @staticmethod decorator, it would work. From this I realized that, VSCode was using python2.7 when running it, but my terminal was using Python 3.6. So after changing path settings in VSCode to execute Python3.6, it was working.